# Owl Carousel Infinity Loop for Wordpress Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Looking to use an infinity loop for the latest Owl Carousel Wordpress plugin. I've downloaded Owl Carousel v2, which has the infinity loop implemented, but the functionality and the Javascript are very different from the Wordpress plugin's versions.

In v2, they list the loop as a default option, but there are no default options in the Wordpress plugin.

```
/**
     * Default options for the carousel.
     * @public
     */
    Owl.Defaults = {
        items: 3,
        loop: false,
        center: false,

        mouseDrag: true,
        touchDrag: true,
        pullDrag: true,
        freeDrag: false,

        margin: 0,
        stagePadding: 0,

        merge: false,
        mergeFit: true,
        autoWidth: false,

        startPosition: 0,
        rtl: false,

        smartSpeed: 250,
        fluidSpeed: false,
        dragEndSpeed: false,

        responsive: {},
        responsiveRefreshRate: 200,
        responsiveBaseElement: window,
        responsiveClass: false,

        fallbackEasing: 'swing',

        info: false,

        nestedItemSelector: false,
        itemElement: 'div',
        stageElement: 'div',
```

I'm not an expert in Javascript, so I am wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Owl Carousel v2 has infinity loop feature that v1 doesn't have, I don't know what's kind of wordpress plugin you are using, please provide a link.

EDITED: There a latest plugin of owl carousel v2 with foogallery as optional for wordpress

https://wordpress.org/plugins/foogallery-owl-carousel-template/

Comment: Ivan, thank you. The v2 code isn't even close to the one that I see here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/owl-carousel/ There zero reference to an infinity loop.

Comment: This plugin uses OwlCarousel v1.3.2 which is outdated, you can modify this plugin in following my edited answer soon.

Comment: No problem. Take your time. I appreciate the help!

Comment: By the way, I found another plugin that comes Owl Carousel v2 with Foo Gallery as optional. Edited Answer